# Magento 2 hide sidebar only in category view for mobile

Tags: category, css, class, magento2.3.5-p1

I am trying to hide sidebar in my magento 2 instance with css only for mobile view and only in category view pages.

I tried:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .category-view .sidebar .sidebar-main {
        display: none;
    }
```

or

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
        .category .sidebar .sidebar-main {
            display: none;
        }
```

but these don't work. Sidebar is still there

The only thing it works is :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
        .sidebar .sidebar-main {
            display: none;
        }
```

but this remove sidebar for whole site.

And I only need to remove the sidebar only in category pages.

Any ideas please?

Is there a way to define classes for define category page sidebar only?

Comment: please use class `catalog-category-view` instead of `category`

Comment: @Pawan Working! Thank you...Please post it as an answer!

Comment: welcome :) glad to know it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use class `catalog-category-view` instead of `category` because there is no such class `category` on category page!

Your code should be:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .catalog-category-view .sidebar .sidebar-main {
        display: none;
}
```